# Desk check fail: Sentences broken up in middle of words and not on spaces

Tags: java, newline, stringbuilder, desk-check

This is part of a whole program. The problem I'm having issues with is when given n, the program is supposed to insert a new line character at the current or last space to make sure that the character count (spaces aren't included in count) never exceeds n before a new line character is inserted. Its current behavior is that it will split words with new line characters. Guarantees: n will never exceed the char count of largest word. Example: n = 9, To be or not to be that is the question. Wanted behavior:

```
To be or not
to be that
is the
question
```

Current behavior:

```
To be or not
 to be th
at is
 the question
```

As you can see, the spaces aren't replaced like intended and words are broken by new line character. I've desk-checked multiple times, and I can't seem to find the problem. Please help!

```
public class Separator {

    int n; //the int in front of read line
    int cCount = 0;  //character counter
    int i;
    int lastSpc;
    char c;  //for character iterator
    String linePart;

    public String separate(int n, String linePart) {
        StringBuilder finLine = new StringBuilder(linePart);

        for (i = 0; i < linePart.length(); i++) {  //inspects each character in string.
            c = linePart.charAt(i);

            if (c == ' ') {                          //determines whether or not char is a space
                if (cCount == n ) {                  //checks char count
                    finLine.replace(i, i, System.lineSeparator());   //adds new line if char count is reached right before space.
                    cCount = 0;
                    lastSpc = i;
                }
                else {
                    lastSpc = i;                     //assigns index to variable so no need to reverse through string.
                }
            }
            else {
                cCount++;
                if (cCount == n) {                      //if char count is reached while inspecting letter, 
                    finLine.replace(lastSpc, lastSpc, System.lineSeparator());      //replaces last space with new line char
                    cCount = i - lastSpc;
                }
            }
        }
        return finLine.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes into finLine no longer match indexes into linePart after the first newline is added. Use finLine instead of linePart to keep the indexing consistant.

```
public String separate(int n, String linePart) {
    StringBuilder finLine = new StringBuilder(linePart);
    int lines_added = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < finLine.length(); i++) {  //inspects each character in string.
        c = finLine.charAt(i);

        if (c == ' ') {                          //determines whether or not char is a space
            if (cCount == n ) {                  //checks char count
                finLine.replace(i, i+1, System.lineSeparator());   //adds new line if char count is reached right before space.
                cCount = 0;
                lastSpc = i ;
            }
            else {
                lastSpc = i;                     //assigns index to variable so no need to reverse through string.
            }
        }
        else {
            cCount++;
            if (cCount == n) {                      //if char count is reached while inspecting letter, 
                finLine.replace(lastSpc, lastSpc+1, System.lineSeparator());      //replaces last space with new line char
                cCount = i - lastSpc;
            }
        }
    }
    return finLine.toString();
}
```

Comment: The new behavior is now a space in front of every line after first and an extra newline in front of question. Thank you for that bit of help though!!

Comment: Edited to replace the space with newline rather than just inserting newline before space.

Comment: Sir, your level of rock is astronomical!